# Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am adding a movie to the base [MovieEntity](https://github.com/JonkiPro/popcorn/blob/develop/popcorn-core/src/main/java/com/jonki/popcorn/core/jpa/entity/movie/MovieInfoEntity.java) class and then another title [MovieOtherEnity](https://github.com/JonkiPro/popcorn/blob/develop/popcorn-core/src/main/java/com/jonki/popcorn/core/jpa/entity/movie/MovieOtherTitleEntity.java) class that inherits from [MovieInfoEntity](https://github.com/JonkiPro/popcorn/blob/develop/popcorn-core/src/main/java/com/jonki/popcorn/core/jpa/entity/movie/MovieInfoEntity.java.)

`MovieInfoEntity` has a foreign key to `MovieEntity`. `MovieEntity` has lists of entities inheriting from the `MovieInfoEntity` class.

I have a test where after each test the base is cleared of objects.

```
/**
 * Clean out the db after every test.
 */
@After
public void cleanup() {
    this.contributionRepository.deleteAll();
    this.messageRepository.deleteAll();
    this.movieRepository.deleteAll(); // here he throws an exception
    this.movieInfoRepository.deleteAll();
    this.userRepository.deleteAll();
}
```

the line marked in the code above is thrown out

```
org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException: Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass [com.jonki.popcorn.core.jpa.entity.movie.MovieBoxOfficeEntity] : loaded object was of wrong class class com.jonki.popcorn.core.jpa.entity.movie.MovieOtherTitleEntity; nested exception is org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass [com.jonki.popcorn.core.jpa.entity.movie.MovieBoxOfficeEntity] : loaded object was of wrong class class com.jonki.popcorn.core.jpa.entity.movie.MovieOtherTitleEntity
```

I will mention that it tests the method, where I added the Object MovieOtherTitle item to the list of the MovieEntity object.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that in the database, you don't have entries (maybe entered manually) that do not have a defined value in the discriminator column or the value in the column is not a DiscriminatorValue of any of your entities. This will only affect retrieval but not saving.

Answer (score 3):

The problem for me was, that i needed to put the DiscrimininatorValue annotation on top

```java
    @DiscriminatorValue("BillAddress")
    public class BillAddress extends Address {
          ...
    }
```

Wasted two hours on this and found the solution here: [jboss forum](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/108917)

Comment: that was it, thanks